# General formula for $\int^1_0 x^\alpha \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2 (x)\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, mathematica

Consider a following definite integral

$$I(\alpha)  = \int^1_0 x^\alpha \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2 (x)\, \mathrm dx$$

*Mathematica* is able to provide a result for many $\alpha$ integers. See table here:

$$\begin{array}{c}
 I(0)=-2 \zeta (3)+3-\frac{\pi ^2}{6} \\
 I(1)=-\zeta (3)+\frac{25}{16}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8} \\
 I(2)=-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{3}+\frac{227}{216}-\frac{11 \pi ^2}{108} \\
 I(3)=-\frac{\zeta (3)}{2}+\frac{5443}{6912}-\frac{25 \pi ^2}{288} \\
 I(4)=-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{5}+\frac{677309}{1080000}-\frac{137 \pi ^2}{1800} \\
 I(5)=-\frac{\zeta (3)}{3}+\frac{673333}{1296000}-\frac{49 \pi ^2}{720} \\
 I(6)=-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{7}+\frac{229495199}{518616000}-\frac{121 \pi ^2}{1960} \\
 I(7)=-\frac{\zeta (3)}{4}+\frac{1824315697}{4741632000}-\frac{761 \pi ^2}{13440} \\
 I(8)=-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{9}+\frac{16317321883}{48009024000}-\frac{7129 \pi ^2}{136080} \\
 I(9)=-\frac{\zeta (3)}{5}+\frac{1946452513}{6401203200}-\frac{7381 \pi ^2}{151200} \\
 I(10)=-\frac{2 \zeta (3)}{11}+\frac{64401732356723}{234300040128000}-\frac{83711 \pi ^2}{1829520} \\
\end{array}$$

Is there a closed form expression for $f,g,h$ in $I(\alpha) = f(\alpha) + g(\alpha)\pi^2 + h(\alpha)\zeta(3)$?

Comment: Have you tried non-integer values? Or are you only asking about the integer case?

Comment: Anyway, I would expand the dilogarithm as a series, then integrate term by term, then see how to sum the result

Comment: I am asking also for noninteger case. However, in a sense of a continuation, if one finds a closed form expression for integers, then it might be possible to extend that formula for noninteger values. I have found so far that $I(\alpha) = f(\alpha) -\frac{H_{\alpha+1}}{6 (\alpha+1)} \pi^2 - 2\zeta(3)/(\alpha+1)$

Comment: Maybe useful - it can be shown that
$$\int_0^1 x^n \operatorname{Li}_2(x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{(n+1)\pi^2-6(\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(n+2))}{6(n+1)^2}$$
Expand $\log(1-x)$ into a convergent Taylor series and use this fact.

Comment: Using Mathematica $$I(\alpha)=-\frac{2\, \zeta (3)}{\alpha +1}+\left(\frac{1}{\alpha +1}\sum _{n=1}^{\alpha +1} \frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{\left(H_{\alpha +1}\right){}^2-\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha +2)}{(\alpha +1)^2}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2 \left((\alpha +1) H_{\alpha +1}-1\right)}{6 \,(\alpha +1)^2}$$ where $\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha)$ is the PolyGamma Function

Comment: with further simplification $$\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha+2)=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\sum _{n=1}^{\alpha +1} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H_{\alpha +1}^{(2)}$$

Comment: @JamesArathoon How exactly can I use *Mathematica* to obtain your result for $I(\alpha)$. How to assuime $\alpha$ is integer? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is immediately revealed by combining the Cauchy product
$$ \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^3}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n} ,\ |x|\le1 \land x\neq1$$
and well-known harmonic series in the mathematical literature.
You might find useful results in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** and in the paper **Euler sum involving tail** by **Moti Levy** and **C.I. Valean**, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339552441_Euler_sum_involving_tail).

More precisely, we need slightly adjusted forms (or we let them the way they
are and rearrange the series result obtained after integration) of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{2n}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}= \zeta(2)\frac{H_n}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{H_i}{i^2},$$
as they appear in the generalization from Sect. **4.16**, page **289** in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

Comment: How exactly we can sum up $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{3-n \left(2 H_n+n H_n^{(2)}\right)}{n^3 (\alpha+n+1)}$ then?

Comment: @Machinato I made a little update. Arrange your series and then split it such that you can use the results I just posted. And you're done!

Comment: A simpler form expressed in terms of harmonic numbers for $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{H_i}{i^2}$ cannot be obtained.

Comment: Marvelous! A last question of mine: Is there a chance that even the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n H_i/i^2$ can be written in an "exact form"? (I.e. in terms of other possible higher order Harmonic coefficients, or polygamma functions)

Comment: The reason I am sure it might be possible is the integral $\int_0^1 q^3 \ln(q) \ln(1-q) \text{Li}_2{q} dq$ which can be expressed as a sum of zeta integer values. This integral (and other changing 3 to any other integer) should be obtained from my original integral by differentiation, which I cannot see, how to differentiate the remaining sum.

Comment: @Machinato I might have something for the series involved, but It will take a while...

Comment: Another thing is this – if the sum term is unexpressible in other harmonic coefficients, how can one obtain $I(\alpha)$ at noninteger values? (At one half for example).

Comment: @Machinato It is an effect of the simple fact that $\displaystyle \psi(n+1/2)=2 H_{2n}-H_n-\gamma-2\log(2)$.

Comment: @Machinato Also, think of the following fact: If you multiply both sides of the last series result by $n$, differentiate it $5$ times and then let $n\to -1$, you get in the left-hand side $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^6}$. And this last result is not known in the literature! Getting good progress at this point means to write a paper and get famous.

Comment: @user97357329 no doubt about it. I was focusing on the part with $H_i/i^2$ sum, in which you cannot plug half integer values of $\alpha$ since the sum must run through integers only.

Comment: @Machinato A happier case would have been to get such a form $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}=\frac{H_n^3+3H_n H_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{3n}.$$ But you are missing $H_k^2$ part. I also thought for a while of writing useful forms for that sum.

Comment: @Machinato my point above, in short, is that with a *simpler form* of that sum in hand we would be able to calculate harmonic series that *have never been discovered with a closed-form* in the mathematical literature as in that example I gave you.  See pages $22$-$23$ here https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1047674270/. At the moment, we are able only to calculate $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^6}$ as a part of a sum with another harmonic series of similar characteristics.

Comment: More generally, the value of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^{2n}}, \ n\ge3,$ is not known in the literature. *Bad news!*

Comment: @user97357329 I am overwhelmed how much is contained within Vălean's book (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums,and Series. However, what I don't like about the book is its nonencyclopedic charater. On the one hand, it is a problem book (but extraordinary complicated,even with hints), on the other, it is ment to list interesting sums and integrals. However, I wouldn't use the book as a handbook of integrals and series, due to obscure naming,(almost) random ordering and not giving exact results for some of problems. Is there a handbook which includes the most of the results given in the book?

Comment: @Machinato absolutely no, there is no such a handbook in the literature. Many of the problems are created by the author, some of them also being proposed and published in mathematical journals. If you spend enough time with the book, at least one, two years, working hard on it, you'll have a very different perspective on it (my guess).

Comment: I think you refer to something like *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, but updates could be made in the future versions of it (this is a reference I got right from the author).

Comment: @Machinato For a technical reference, see arxiv $2007.03957$. This might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You did a great job in finding $g(\alpha)$ and $h(\alpha)$. Yet in my opinion there is no way to find a general expression for $f(\alpha)$.

My doubts are explained through a simple analysis of the first six pure coefficients:

$$3 ~~~~~ \frac{25}{16} ~~~~~ \frac{227}{216} ~~~~~ \frac{5443}{6912} ~~~~~ \frac{677309}{1080000} ~~~~~ \frac{673333}{1296000}$$

Writing them in terms of primes we have ($p$ denotes a pure prime):

$$p ~~~~~ \frac{5^2}{2^4} ~~~~~ \frac{p}{2^3 3^3} ~~~~~ \frac{p}{2^8 3^3} ~~~~~\frac{p}{2^6 3^3 5^4} ~~~~~ \frac{419 \times 1607}{2^7 3^4 5^3}$$

- It's a rather messy series, where second and sixth numerators are not primes, whilst others are.
- Analysing the denominators, we do not recognise a pattern in terms of the exponents concerning the first three primes.
- The sixth numerator is relatively close to the previous one, rather irregular for a pattern.

So this is my opinion: there is no general expression for $f(\alpha)$.

However I could be wrong, and I could have missed something very subtle someone else might notice!
Maybe my very rude and simple analysis can lead someone to something else (better, new, more argumentative), so who knows!

That's the beauty of maths and numbers.

Comment: After couple of hours of trying what may fit, I have found a value for $f(\alpha)$, however, I am not satisfied with that result. I was able to fit the pattern using this formula: $f(\alpha) = y(\alpha )+\frac{\left(H_{1+\alpha }\right){}^2}{(1+\alpha )^2}+\frac{H_{1+\alpha }^{(2)}}{(1+\alpha )^2}+\frac{H_{1+\alpha }^{(3)}}{4
   (1+\alpha )}$, where $y$ satisfies this reccurence relation: $-9 -4n+4(1+n) (2+n)^3 (3 +n) y(n)- 
  4 (2+n)^2 (3+n) (13+10n+2 n^2) y(1+n) + 
  4 (2 + n) (3 + n)^4 y(2+n)=0$ with $y(1)=35/64, y(2)=371/864$. Is there a way to express $y$ in terms of harmonic numbers?

Comment: @Machinato Astounding! I will check this better later!

Comment: A bit simpler reccurence formula: $f(\alpha) = y(\alpha)+\frac{\left(H_{a+1}^{(1)}\right){}^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{H_{a+1}^{(2)}}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{H_{a+1}^{(3)}}{a+1}$ with $(1+n) (2+n)^3 y(n)-(2+n)^2 \left(13+10 n+2 n^2\right) y(1+n)+(2+n) (3+n)^3 y(2+n)=1$ with initial values $y(1)=\frac{1}{8},y(2)=\frac{5}{36}$

Answer (score 1):

**Long Comment On Coaxing an Answer From Mathematica 12: (in answer to comment from O.P.)**

Mathematica can't symbolically evaluate
$$I(\alpha)=\int^1_0 x^\alpha \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2 (x)\, \mathrm dx$$
directly.

Therefore trying integrating by parts with $\int x^{\alpha } \log (1-x) \, dx=\frac{x^{\alpha +1} \log (1-x)+B_x(\alpha +2,0)}{\alpha +1}$ and $\frac{d\, \text{Li}_2(x)}{dx}=-\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}$, both of which Mathematica is happy with.

Mathematica can find the limits $x\to 1$ and $x\to 0$ to evaluate

$$\left[\frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \left(x^{\alpha +1} \log (1-x)+B_x(\alpha +2,0)\right)}{\alpha +1}\right]^1_0$$

e.g. using

```
Limit[((Beta[x, 2 + \[Alpha], 0] + x^(1 + \[Alpha]) Log[1 - x])/(1 + \[Alpha])) PolyLog[2, x], x -> 1]
```

Mathematica can evaluate the integral,

$$-\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha } \log ^2(1-x)}{\alpha +1} \, dx = -\frac{-6 \psi ^{(1)}(\alpha +2)+6 \left(H_{\alpha +1}\right){}^2+\pi ^2}{(\alpha +1) (6 \alpha +6)}$$

but then fails to evaluate:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(-\log (1-x)) B_x(\alpha +2,0)}{(\alpha +1) x} \, dx.$$

However this is easily solved by substituting in the infinite series for the Incomplete Beta Function in this case

$$B_x(\alpha +2,0)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{\alpha +n+2}}{\alpha +n+2}$$

and then by changing the order of the resulting integral and summation we have

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha +n+1}(-\log (1-x)) }{(\alpha +1) (\alpha +n+2)} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{H_{n+\alpha +2}}{(\alpha +1) (\alpha +n+2)^2}$$

Then its just a matter of rearranging, changing the summations to start from $n=1$ and simplifying where necessary.